# How to troubleshoot MVC/Identity 2 authentication timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

User authenticates, but is becoming unauthenticated within a minute or minutes. Seems to happen at random, but is within a handful of minutes.

Is there a breakpoint I can set someplace where logout is occurring , or a method of troubleshooting why a user is being logged out?

This doesn't seem to happen on localhost when running the project using VS, but is happening on the remote host after publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Set the session state in IIS or the web.config:

```
<system.web>
        <sessionState timeout="60"/>
        ...
```

That sets the timeout to be 60 minutes. You should also lookup [session state modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: I do have `sessionState` set in Web.config. Actually set it to 180, but users are still becoming unauthenticated within a handful of minutes.

Comment: Is your app pool set to recycle? This could case the sessions to be lost. Try changing that setting in IIS or try the sql session storage option.